# How to set livestream pipeline to PAUSED without GST_STATE_CHANGE_NO_PREROLL

Tags: gstreamer

I've got this pipeline: udpsrc, rtph264depay, tee, avdec_h264, clockoverlay,autovideosink
when it's playing i want to add this elements to tee: mpegtsmux, filesink.

What is right for me to do?

I think that I have to set pipeline to PAUSE, add the elements, link them and start the pipelin, but
when i'm trying to set pipe to PAUSED it returns GST_STATE_CHANGE_NO_PREROLL to me...
and i can't link tee and mpegtsmux (with GST_PAD_LINK_NOFORMAT)
and afterthat i'm trying to set pipe to PLAYING and got this again GST_STATE_CHANGE_NO_PREROLL...

I'm using old gstreamer - 0.10, and for some reasones can't use gstreamer 1.0

Answer (score 0):

the NOFORMAT error means that the elements involved can't find a common format for using. You are likely missing an h264parse before the muxer.

In any case I *strongly* recommend that you upgrade to 1.x as dynamic pipelines are much easier in it, left aside the fact that 0.10 is obsolete and unmantained for a long time.